# Selecting multiple dynamic ranges without union

Tags: vba, excel

I need to select multiple ranges that follow the form ("B1:D" & n + 2), for every three column up to ("AI1:AK" & n + 2), giving twelve ranges in total. I don't want to use union as I need to add a border around each one (whereas union would add a border around the edge of all the ranges), but I can't seem to select all of the ranges.

Is there a way that I can select all of the ranges without using union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with multiple ranges with something like `Range("A1:A2, C2:D4")`.

For your example try something like:

```
Sub PickMultipleAreas()
Dim n As Long

n = 2
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("B1:D" & n + 2 & "," & _
           "AI1:AK" & n + 2).BorderAround ColorIndex:=3, Weight:=xlThick
End With
End Sub
```

For more on this concept and a tool I wrote to de-select overlapping ranges, see: http://yoursumbuddy.com/undo-selections-selectracker/

Answer (score 2):

`For Next` Loop would do the trick:

```
For i = 2 to 35 Step 3
    Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(n + 2, i + 2)).BorderAround 'your criteria here
Next i
```

or using `Offset()`

```
For i = 0 to 11
    Range("B1:D" & n + 2).Offset(0, i * 3).BorderAround 'your criteria here
Next i
```

Both tested working.

Comment: I've already accepted Doug's answer, but this works briliiantly as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Moogle No prob.  Just a little slow on my typing.  I appreciate the upvote tho!

Comment: Realistically, this is a better approach than mine. I was being literal, this is more practical.